# How to view Ansible documentation in terminal?

Tags: ansible, documentation, ansible-inventory

Is it possible to view the same information received from this url: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html#play
using the `ansible-doc`/`ànsible` command in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

`ansible-doc` will extract documentation for a particular plugin depending on its type by extracting the corresponding `DOCUMENTATION` declaration directly from the source file.

You can have a look at all files known to ansible doc for a particular type of plugin with `ansible-doc -t <type> -F`

In your particular case, the doc page you reference is an appendice which is not extracted directly from sources. I actually have no idea if it is available / forkable / changeable from an external source. Meanwhile, `ansible-doc` will not be able to return this type of doc, at least not in its current version.